# Simple Confusing Loops and Variable working

Tags: javascript

In this question,I'm asking how the following snippets work, as it involves weird use of variable:

```
while (+(+i--)!=0)
{
    i-=i++;
}
console.log(i);
```

Comment: What is the initial value of `i`?

Comment: This *has* to be undefined behavior.

Comment: in C, I think i -= i++ is undefined behaviour, but I am not sure --- :)

Comment: In C, it is undefined behaviour. In Java, there is no such thing as undefined behaviour! So it's odd, but it does have a defined meaning. In JavaScript, I'm not so sure. See my answer for full details.

Comment: @Oltarus I guess we're just supposed to describe what it does, no matter what the initial value of `i` is. (You can imagine that it's a function that takes `i` as an argument -- what does the function do?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem... you've tagged it Java, JavaScript and C -- note that while these languages have the same syntax, this question involves very subtle semantics that may (I'm not sure) differ across languages.

Let's break it down:

```
+(+i--)
```

The `--` postfix decrement operator is most tightly bound. So this is equivalent to `+(+(i--))`. That is therefore equivalent to the value of `+(+i)` (that is, `i`), but it also decrements `i` after taking the value. It compares the value with 0 to see if the loop should continue. Thus, `while (+(+i--)!=0)` is equivalent to the following:

```
while (i-- != 0)
```

Note that it also performs `i--` at the end of the loop.

Inside the loop, I believe you have some undefined behaviour, at least in C, because you are referencing `i` on the right, and also updating `i` on the left -- I believe that C doesn't define which order to do that in. So your results will probably vary from compiler to compiler. Java, at least, is consistent, so I'll give the Java answer. `i-=i++` is equivalent `i = i - i++`, which is equivalent to to *reading* all the values out of the expression, *computing* the result of the expression, *applying the post-increment*, and then *assigning* the result back. That is:

```
int t = i - i;    // Calculate the result of the expression "i - i++"
i++;              // Post-increment i
i = t;            // Store the result back
```

Clearly, this is the same as writing `i = 0`. So the body of the loop sets i to 0.

Thus, the loop executes just one time, setting i to 0. Then, it decrements `i` one more time on the next while loop, but fails the check because `i` (before decrementing) == 0.

Hence, the final answer is `-1`, no matter what the initial value for `i` is.

To put this all together and write an equivalent program:

```
while (i-- != 0)
{
    int t = i - i;
    i++;
    i = t;
}
console.log(i);
```

When I tried it in Java and JavaScript, that's what I got. For GCC (C compiler), it gives -1 only when `i` starts out as 0. If `i` starts out as anything else, it goes into an infinite loop.

That's because in GCC (not necessarily all C compilers), `i-=i++` has a different meaning: it does the store back to `i` first, *then* does the post-increment. Therefore, it is equivalent to this:

```
int t = i - i;    // Calculate the result of the expression "i - i++"
i = t;            // Store the result back
i++;              // Post-increment i
```

That's equivalent to writing `i = 1`. Therefore, on the first iteration, it sets `i` to 1, and then on the loop, it checks whether `i == 0`, and it isn't, so it goes around again, always setting `i` to 1. This will never terminate, but for the special case where `i` starts out as 0; then it will always terminate the loop and decrement `i` (so you get `-1`).

Another C compiler may choose to act like Java instead. This shows that you should *never* write code which both assigns and postincrements the same variable: you never know what will happen!

**Edit**: I tried to be too clever using that `for` loop; that wasn't equivalent. Turned back into a while loop.

Comment: Note: Obviously the `console.log` I changed to the equivalent print statements in Java and C, but otherwise this is how it works on all those languages.

Comment: Thank you man, actually this problem was having initial value as i=0, and Now I got it how it works.

Comment: One important item abut the `i-=i++` line in C/C++: it's undefined behavior.  So trying to reason about what will happen is pointless - it's a bug plain and simple and anything can happen.

Comment: @Michael Burr I thought I made it pretty clear on several occasions in my answer that it was undefined behaviour. "you have some undefined behaviour, at least in C," "your results will probably vary from compiler to compiler," "in GCC (not necessarily all C compilers)," "Another C compiler may choose to act like Java instead. This shows that you should never write code which both assigns and postincrements the same variable: you never know what will happen!"

Answer (score 1):

That's soooo wierd! (I love it)

first, you can forget about the `+(+`...`)` part, it's just like saying `1 + (+1) = 2`.

`i--` means `i = i - 1`. In your `while` condition, you test if `i--` is different from `0`. Note: the test is made on `i != 0` and then `i`'s value is changed. If you wanted to change its value **before** the test, you should have used `--i` instead.

As for the `i -= i++`, it's a very dumb way to say `i = 0`. You must read it from right to left: `i = i + 1` and then `i = i - i`<sup>1</sup> (whatever value of `i` you have, you'll end up with `0`.

Simplier quivalent snippet:

```
while (i-- != 0) {
  i = 0;
}
console.log(i);
```

<sup>1</sup> `a -= b` means `a = a - b`.

Comment: Good answer -- almost true, but it depends on the language (this is correct for Java. For C it's undefined and for JavaScript, I don't know).

Comment: @mgiuca True. I only tested with Java. Which leaves @Delma Pawan with 2/3 of homework to do...

Comment: Won't `i-=i++' leave i equal to 1? It subtracts it from itself then increments...which looks to me like it would create an endless loop because it guarantees i will always be non-zero when evaluating the while condition (except for the first time in; we aren't told what i is just before the loop).

Comment: @Oltarus True, there's something to be said for letting people do their own homework. But I did want to answer completely.

Comment: @nnnnnn That's the undefined behaviour I was talking about. A C compiler is legally allowed to either do what Oltarus suggests (first increment i then store 0), or what you suggest (first store 0 then increment). Java always behaves the way Oltarus suggests. My C compiler (GCC) behaves the way you suggest, resulting in an infinite loop. See my answer for a full description.

Comment: @nnnnnn Answer for Java: Nope, when assigning a value to a variable, you first resolve the right part. So first, you calculate `i++` and then you subtract it to `i` (which just has been modified. I tried, the debugger says `i`'s value is `0` just after this line.

Comment: @Oltarus & @mgiuca - yep, I just tried it out in JavaScript and I got 0 too. I think I was confused by vague memories of when I first learnt C at uni: I couldn't remember the exact rule until you spelled it out for me. Plus I didn't notice that the question was tagged with all three languages.

Comment: @oltarus: I think Leftmost part is resolved first,that's why L-part needed exception arise sometimes in other places.

Answer (score 0):

`i -= i++` would mean a similar thing to `i = i-i; i++` (if you make the `-=` explicit).

In a similar fashion, you can pull the side effect of `i--` out of the loop condition by
transforming `while (foo(i--)) { ... }` to `while (foo(i)) { i--; ...} i--;` (you need to put it both in the loop body and after the loop because, at the end, the condition will be false and the loop body will not be executed but execution continues after the while loop).

Answer (score 0):

The while condition evaluation happens based on operator precedence. I have used explicit braces to help understand the evaluation:

(+(+(i--)) != 0) which is equivalent to using (i-- != 0) as the '+' are just unary operators.

The expression i -=i++; is equivalent to i = i - i++; where the LHS expression gets evaluated from left to right.

```
i = 4;
while (+(+i--)!=0)  //here i would be decremented once to 3.
{     
     i-=i++; // here i = 3 - 3 = 0; even though i has been incremented by 1 its value is set to 0 with this assignment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. And I think the only reason to code like this is a concept called "code obfucasion" or "code confusing". This way makes the code harder to read and debug, so that can prevent from reverse engineer your code :-)

Comment: I know man, this question was asked to me in one of the Recruitment TECHNICAL exam .